# Spread operator in console and html element

Tags: javascript

Given an array of strings,

```js
const bestRappers = ["Ice Cube", "MC Eiht", "Eazy-E"]
const output = document.getElementById('output')

/* 1: */ console.log(...bestRappers)
/* 2: */ output.innerText = [...bestRappers]
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

2 returns the items seperated by commas. 1 Isn´t seperated. Why?

Comment: 1 is equivalent to `console.log('A', 'B', 'C')`, while 2 is equivalent to `['A', 'B', 'C'].toString()`, and `Array.toString` joins its items with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a spread operator does is take an iterable(in your case array) and give it as n number of arguments.

In first case
console.log is a function so it gives it 3 arguments
console.log(...bestRappers) ---> console.log(Ice Cube,MC Eiht,Eazy-E) so generally console.log function logs every argument space separated

In second case you spread the array into an array again ([...bestRappers]) so when you assign array to an innerText it displays as comma separated values

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the same output in your console like in your dom then you have to use the JavaScript `join()` function with comma as seperator.

**working example**

```js
bestRappers = ["Ice Cube", "MC Eiht", "Eazy-E"];

console.log(bestRappers.join(', '));
output.innerText = [...bestRappers]
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```